# “No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present” error for some requests but not others

Tags: python, vue.js, amazon-s3, flask, cors

I have a VueJS app running on S3 that is served by a Flask-powered API running on AWS Elastic Beastalk.

**The problem**

When making *some* requests, I get the following:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.myflaskapi.net/blueprint/get_info?date=2019-01-01' from origin 'https://app.myvuejsapp.net' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

**What I've done so far**

In my `__init__.py` file, initialized by the app factory in Flask I have set `CORS(app, support_credentials=True)` as the example on [this link](https://flask-cors.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#examples). With that, I would hope that basically any request would have the CORS heading, so I wouldn't have any policy blocking my frontend requests.

The ideal scenario would be to only allow requests from `https://app.myvuejsapp.net`, so I tried using `CORS(app, support_credentials=True, origins=['https://app.myvuejsapp.net'])` but also without success.

I've also tried making one CORS instance for each of my blueprints with `CORS(myblueprint)` for each `.py` route file (I have one for each blueprint), also without success.

The strange thing is, I do have one function on Vue that runs when the app is `mounted` that works just fine. I can't see any difference between this and other functions that won't work.

Example of working function (returns `true` or `false` from the backend):

```
      checkDB() {
        const path = this.base_url + 'blueprint/check_db'
        axios.get(path, this.token)
          .then(checkupd => {
            this.isupdated = Boolean(checkupd.data);
            if (this.isupdated == true) {
              this.update_msg = "Database up to date."
              this.loading = false
              this.finished = true
            } else {
              this.update_msg = "WARNING: Check DB status."
            }
          })
          .catch(error => {
            console.log(error)
          })
      },
```

Example of non-working function (returns a XLS from the backend):

```
      getSalesFrom(file) {
        const fs = require('fs')
        const FileDownload = require('js-file-download');
        const path = this.base_url + `blueprint/get_sales?date=${this.date}`
        axios.get(path, {
            headers: 
              {
                "X-Access-Token": "mytoken",
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
              },
            responseType: 'blob'
          })
          .then(response => {
            const content = response.headers['content-type'];
            download(response.data, 'text.xlsx', content)
          })
          .catch(error => {
            console.log(error)
          })
        this.export_dialog = false
      }
```

**S3 CORS Configuration XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
    <AllowedHeader>Authorization</AllowedHeader>
    <AllowedHeader>Content-Length</AllowedHeader>
    <AllowedHeader>Access-Control-Allow-Origin</AllowedHeader>
    <AllowedHeader>X-Access-Token</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

Any ideas on what I might be doing wrong?
I've been reading for a while, but can't seem to find a solution for what it seems a pretty simple problem... Maybe I should mess with the S3 bucket permission configuration?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you try this **cors = CORS(app, resources={r"/*": {"origins": "https://app.myvuejsapp.net"}})**

Comment: Nothing... same error - also tried adding `https` in front of the origin.

Comment: Now I see you are sending custom headers with your request, so can you try adding **'Access-Control-Request-Headers': '*'** to your response header ?

Comment: Yes, I use `X-Access-Token` to send my token (don't know if it is a good approach, but it is what it is for now). @onuriltan, don't know how to do that exactly, any links to guide me on how to add that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any time you run into a case where you’re seeing a *“No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present”* message for some requests but not others, use the Network pane in browser devtools to check the HTTP status code of the response.

Almost always what you’re going to find is that the HTTP status code in those cases is a 4xx or 5xx error instead of the expected 200 OK success response.

The only reason you see the *“No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present”* message is those cases is, the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header typically isn’t going to get added to 4xx and 5xx errors. Part of the reason is, in the 5xx case especially, the cause can be a server failure that occurs before the server ever gets around to running your application code. Along with that, most servers by default won’t add application-set response headers to 4xx and 5xx errors; instead by default they only add them to 2xx success responses.

So anyway, what you want to do is, look at the server logs on the server side (for the server you’re sending the request to) and see what messages the server is logging about the cause of whatever problem it is that makes the server end up sending that 4xx or 5xx error response.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand correctly you host your `Vue.js` application from `S3`.

You need to include `CORS` headers in your `S3` buckets. Without them the browser will block all requests to your Flask application. You are making requests to `api.myflaskapi.net` from `app.myvuejsapp.net` so you need configure `CORS` in `app.myvuejsapp.net`.

You can read documentation how to set `CORS` in `S3` [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors.html) and [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/add-cors-configuration.html).

> To configure your bucket to allow cross-origin requests, you create a CORS configuration, which is an XML document with rules that identify the origins that you will allow to access your bucket, the operations (HTTP methods) that will support for each origin, and other operation-specific information.
>
> You can add up to 100 rules to the configuration. You add the XML document as the cors subresource to the bucket either programmatically or by using the Amazon S3 console. For more information, see [Enabling Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ManageCorsUsing.html).

Comment: Yes, you are correct, the `Vue.js` app is hosted in S3. I just edited the question including the configuration I'm using in the bucket.